# Flutter Firebase where query

Tags: database, list, firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

Lets imagine I have a list with Document ids e.g

`List documentIds = ["Tj4EB68R1CwBYKPfWzcm","fExzUQbpzjEbGyE8mKDa","yPQvLLN7hkDFCjKN6mky"];`

Now I want to get all Documents that match that id.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for a `whereIn` query, which looks like this:

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance
  .collection('yourdocuments')
  .where(FieldPath.documentId, whereIn: documentIds)
  .get()
  .then(...);
```

The list of document IDs can be up to 10 long, so if you have more than 10 document IDs you'll need to run multiple queries and merge the results in your application code.

See also:

- The FlutterFire documentation for [querying Firestore](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage#querying)
- The reference documentation for [`Query.where()`](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/Query/where.html)
- The reference documentation for [`FieldPath.documentId`](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore_platform_interface/latest/cloud_firestore_platform_interface/FieldPath/documentId.html).

Comment: Ok thank you I also saw that  but the Problem is I have more than 10 ids could you show me an example with the solution for more than 10 ids